# suggestions on a project in C++ / distributed systems / networks

Tags: c++, networking, distributed-computing, gpu

I'd like to work on a 2-3 month long project (full time) that involves coding in C++ and is related to networks (protocol stacks). I was considering writing my own network stack but that doesn't seem as interesting. It would be great to find an idea to implement a tcp/ip-like stack for distributed system/GPUs that is better as far as network performance goes. I have been googling this for 3 hours but haven't come across anything that seems worth spending 2 months on. Open source projects like netperf seem beyond my scope. I'd really like a relatively small stand alone project that I can work on, at my own pace.
The intent of this project is to utilize my free time on a project (that I might later release under open source license) and gain expertise and hands-on experience in C++, networks, parallel programming, GPU, distributed systems etc.

I seem to have hit a roadblock while finding ideas (or perhaps I am not too clear on what I exactly what to do). So any suggestions would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are specifically interested in doing network programming with an emphasis on distribution and GPU/graphics stuff, you may want to check out the open source (GPL) [CIGI project](http://cigi.sourceforge.net/index.php) ([sourceforge project site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cigi/):

> CIGI is an open simulation protocol for communication between a host device and IG (image generator). 
>   The Common Image Generator Interface (CIGI) is an interface designed to promote a standard 
>   way for a host device to communicate with an image generator (IG) in the simulation industry.

CIGI is a [fairly active project on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/project/stats/index.php?group_id=39061&ugn=cigi), initiated and backed by [BOEING](http://www.sisostds.org/index.php?tg=articles&idx=Print&topics=114&article=452), and is multi-platform software:

> The goal of the Common Image Generator Interface (CIGI) SG is to evaluate
>   industry and government interest in developing a standard image generator
>   interface. Typically, today's Image Generator (IG) vendors have their own
>   closed, proprietary run-time interfaces. At I/ITSEC'02, Boeing
>   proposed their Open Source Common Image Generator Interface (CIGI) as a
>   run-time interface that could be adopted by the simulation community.
>   Boeing indicated that they would like to see a standards organization adopt
>   CIGI and develop it into a robust and broadly accepted simulation industry
>   image generator run-time interface standard. The SG is discussing this
>   proposal, evaluating alternatives, and generating recommendations and a
>   proposed action plan.

[Here's some wireshark-based info on CIGI](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CIGI)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Ace Wrappers. http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html
It provide well tested pattern based C++ implementation for distributed network programming.

Answer (score 0):

Do distributed audio/video with [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol).  Extend an Open Source SIP client and/or server to use SCTP to scale better.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a project on ad-hoc communication networks between vehicles.  There is an open-source traffic simulation model called SUMO which you can leverage.  The wiki for SUMO lists a bunch of existing research and tools that you can use as a starting point:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sumo/index.php?title=Main_Page#Related_to_C2C